# what is a letterbox logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

What is meant by a letterbox logo ? the client asked for the logo to be more like a letterbox than a portrait or a landscape so what does it mean for the logo to be a letterbox?

Comment: Best to ask the client if they use a term you are unclear about.

Comment: @Scott -  okay, you are totally right ! Thanks.

Comment: If someone knows a definitive answer Ill reopen but I don't believe one exists in which case @Scott is correct.

Answer (score 1):

When talking about letter box they are referring most likely to the shape of the design. Less of a square more of the shape of an envelope. there is no specific ratio but think about the shape of an envelope almost like a 4:1 width:height ratio or higher.

Look at the GD:SE logo above as an example.

[image]

at least this is my interpretation.

example:

[image]

Just think of the shape of a letterbox on a door

[image]

Comment: can you provide another example ?

Comment: What  about a letterbox movie? It's got a different aspect ratio than a door mail slot. Which is *never* called a "letterbox" in the United States.. which is why I think the *only* real answer is to ask the client what they mean. What I think a "letterbox" is may be entirely different than what the client thinks "letterbox" means.

Comment: i.e.  what if the client means [THIS LETTERBOX](http://www.letterboxing.info/im/postal_letterbox.jpg)? Or [these](http://www.schoolphotoproject.com/_picture-of-objects/mailbox-photo3-l.jpg)?

Comment: While I agree that talking to the client to further explain what they are asking for is important, and will help to better clarify the look they are going for since "letterbox" isn't a clear definition, letterbox as it applies to film is similar while also being different. in film letterbox is adding black boxes to frame the film to a desired shape. A lot of the time this means creating a long slender view. I don't think we can apply the film definition to a logo.

Comment: :0 But then a mail definition doesn't really fit a logo either :) -- Sorry.. not meaning to sound as though i was arguing the point. I'm not. :)

Comment: No I agree this is completely up for interpretation, which is why I stated "This is my interpretation", Im just making my guess/answer based off recent design trends and ways I have heard this style referred to in the past.